# Exactly one route not working after deployed on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I have a react app in which i open a new tab to view products using a window.open(). This is working perfectly fine when i am working locally but after i deployed it to netlify that particular route says `Page Not Found` Error.

Below is my App.js

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

// for components
import AdminProtectRoute from "./components/AdminProtectRoute";
import UserProtectRoute from "./components/UserProtectRoute";
import Spinner from "./components/Spinner";

// for user
const BookDetails = lazy(() => import("./components/user/BookDetails"));
const UserInventory = lazy(() => import("./components/user/UserInventory"));
const UserIssuedBooks = lazy(() => import("./components/user/UserIssuedBooks"));
const UserRequested = lazy(() => import("./components/user/UserRequested"));
const ForgotLink = lazy(() => import("./components/user/ForgotLink"));
const ForgotPass = lazy(() => import("./components/user/ForgotPass"));
const Contact = lazy(() => import("./components/user/Contact"));
const WishList = lazy(() => import("./components/user/WishList"));
const MyAccount = lazy(() => import("./components/user/MyAccount"));
const EditProfile = lazy(() => import("./components/user/EditProfile"));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ToastContainer />
      <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
          <Routes>
            <Route element={<UserProtectRoute />}>
              <Route path="/users" element={<User />}>
                <Route index path="userissued" element={<UserIssuedBooks />} />
                <Route path="userrequested" element={<UserRequested />} />
                <Route path="userinventory" element={<UserInventory />} />
                <Route path=":bookId" element={<BookDetails />} />        // this route is not working
                <Route path="wishlist" element={<WishList />} />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/account" element={<MyAccount />} />
              <Route path="/edit-profile" element={<EditProfile />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below i my handler function in one of my components which is triggered by a button click that creates a new tab for that `:bookId` route:

```
const handleView = () => {
    window.open('http://localhost:3000/users/' + book._id, "_blank")
  }
```

When i replace `http://localhost:3000` with `https://my_app.netlify.app` and deploy it, this function creates a new tab but gives me "Page not Found" Error but locally it creates a new tab and renders the required component as well.

Also i tried to enter the `:bookId` in my same tabs url search bar like given below:

```
https://my_app.netlify.app/users/63cb6d482ef3b2
```

but even this is not working

I tried my solve this but i unable to do so. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup the redirects, create a `netlify.toml` in the root of your project, and add something like:

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/*"
to = "/"
status = 200
```

Check : https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#redirects

Comment: I've used the Netlify documentation, pretty similar way of dealing with routes -> https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/angular